# Python mss not taking screenshots of a Fullscreen Game

Tags: python

I have the following Python Script:

```
import mss
import time
import pytesseract
import pydirectinput
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
from pytesseract import Output
from PIL import Image

monitor = {"top": 500, "left": 1400, "width": 500, "height": 600}

while True:
    with mss.mss() as sct:
        output = "screenshot.png".format(**monitor)
        sct = sct.grab(monitor)
        mss.tools.to_png(sct.rgb, sct.size, output=output)
```

This works perfectly fine on my desktop, however, when I am tabbed into a game in Fullscreen, it stops taking any screenshots.

As soon as I tab in, it takes ones last screenshot but then stops. The script doesn't stop and throws no errors.

How can I make it continue taking screenshots?

Comment: `output = "screenshot.png".format(**monitor)` That string does not contain any formatting tokens.  What are you expecting `.format()` to do?